# send broadcast intent to only one application without using explicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem. I'm doing a external android service where applications can register to it to receive information. The information come back to the apps from the service via broadcast, and receive it with a `broadcastReceiver`.

The problem is if I do `sendBroadcast`, any app can listen the information that is for others, I can use the category on the intent filter, but both apps can have it the same category, or a malicous app can do this one on pourpose.

A solution is explicit intents, but for this I need the app to register with the package and the class where it will receive the intent. I don't like this solution.

I think there exists another solution, because GCM does so similar and doesn't need anything but the `broadcastreceiver`

I add a small diagram:

[image]

Does the possibility exist to send a broadcast only to a specific app, without defining the class??

How GCM does it?

Comment: I guess your broadcast does so, if you have same broadcast names for two application it will create problem sometime that indicates there comes some problems sometime!

Comment: my problem it is a general prouposes service, and I want prevent malicious app that try take the places of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your concern is in how to have the service send information back to the clients, securely.

In that case, you can use a `PendingIntent`.

A `PendingIntent` is `Parcelable`, and so it is easy for the clients to deliver to the service. Your service can track these and `send()` them as needed, supplying additional data to be put into the `Intent` extras for the `Intent` wrapped by the `PendingIntent`.

The component that will respond to the `PendingIntent` -- activity, service, or receiver -- does not need to be exported.

Comment: That sounds great, but can I use a PendingIntent more that one time? I can't really understand how GCM does this one, because it is a really similar problem. I figure out that with the context the have access to the package but this is not enough to send a explicit intent :S.

Comment: @flipper83: "but can I use a PendingIntent more that one time?" -- yes.