# How to send an intent to only 1 app

Tags: java, android

I broadcast an intent like this

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.my_app_two");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I only want com.my_app_two to get it.

I tried adding an extra to check but there has to be an easier way.

Comment: Just add `setPackage` to say which app should respond

Comment: @njzk2 that solved it. How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `setPackage`

There I can specify which package should receive the intent.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into using a Pendingintent instead of a broadcast as suggested in this answer as well ? 
[send broadcast intent to only one application without using explicit intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141893/send-broadcast-intent-to-only-one-application-without-using-explicit-intent)